# Example of a continuous function from a finite topological space to another finite topological space.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was hoping for a routinely succinct way of doing this:

I was considering taking the topology $(A,O_A)$ where $A=\emptyset$ and $O_A=P(A)=\{\emptyset\}$ and then maybe any other finite topological space $(B,O_B)$ where $O_B$ is again the discrete topology so that every set is open, and maybe just doing $B = \{b\}$.

My confusion then comes from defining my continuous function $f$ and regarding the preimage of say $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ where $f:A\rightarrow B$ would just be the empty function...

I'm going off this definition of a continuous function from one topological space to another:

Given two topological spaces $(X,O_X)$ and $(Y,O_Y)$ a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of any open set is open.  Meaning that, for any open set $V\subseteq Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(V)=\{x\in X | f(x) \in V\subseteq Y\}$ is open.

I am likely to just swap things around and do $f:B\rightarrow A$ but any insight on evaluating $f:A\rightarrow B$ as being continuous would be helpful!

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. I suggest you sharpen it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function f from the empty space E into any other space S
is continuous because f$^{-1}$(U) for any set U is empty.

On the other hand the only function into E is the empty function.
Thus every function from E or into E is continuous.

E is the only space with exactly one open set.
Is E T$_0$, T$_1$, Hausdorff, regular, etc.?
Is E connected, disconnected, discrete, metrizable?